# Why connectors become smaller as frequency increases

Tags: rf

Why connectors size get smaller as frequency increases? For ex: 1.85mm connector is smaller compared to 2.4mm and 2.4mm is smaller compared to 3.5 mm. I think skin effect maybe one reason but I believe there are other reasons.. can somebody advice..

Answer (score 2):

The answer is actually modes. A coaxial connector is, electrically, essentially a short piece of coaxial waveguide.

Up to some cut-off frequency, signals are able to propagate along the waveguide in only one [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode). Above the cut-off frequency, two or more modes can propagate. Since different modes propagate with different axial velocities, portions of the energy of a too-high frequency signal launched in one end of the waveguide will arrive at the other end at different times, resulting in distortion for signals containing more than one frequency.

A larger diameter would actually reduce the effect of skin effect, by providing a larger total conductive cross section (\$2 \pi r \delta\$, where \$r\$ is the radius of the center conductor, and \$\delta\$ is the skin depth at some transmission frequency), thus reducing resistive loss. You will in fact find that coaxial cable designed for higher frequencies (and typically used with 2.4 or 1.85-mm connectors) has higher loss per meter for this reason.

Comment: Still confused.. My doubt is in order to reduce the loss, total conductive cross of connector should increase as frequency increases? But connector sizes tend to reduce as frequency increases.For ex 1mm connector is the smallest.

Comment: @Geo, it's 7 years later but the point is that higher loss (which marginally degrades your signal) is the trade-off you pay to avoid multi-mode propagation (which totally mucks up your signal).